# SSH CA for managing Github SSH Certificates

Tags: certificate-authority, ssh, openssh, github

Github now support authentication via an OpenSSH certificate: https://github.blog/2019-08-14-ssh-certificate-authentication-for-github-enterprise-cloud/.

However, I cannot find any recomendations for a certificate authority to manage these SSH certificates.

There seem to be numerous options surrounding certificate management for servers and productions environments, e.g. BLESS, CASSH etc.

**What would you recommend for managing SSH certificates for developers to access Github?**

In an ideal world, this would allow for custom configuration by developer. It would be able to interact with an existing active directory to authenticate users attempting to create certificates and it would be a managed service.

Comment: You need to set up a CA. How to do that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @schroeder Not really. It's a single command line. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f my_ca -C "My CA"`

Answer (score 2):

I work at [smallstep](https://smallstep.com) and we have an [open source certificate authority](https://github.com/smallstep/certificates) that can issue SSH certificates. We also have a hosted product that does [single sign-on for SSH](https://smallstep.com/sso-ssh/) (along with auto-provisioning of posix users, SSH and `sudo` access control, and audit logging). Both the open source and productized versions allow you to connect certificate issuance to your single sign-on provider using OAuth OIDC. See [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2NSb12mzYI) for an example of the end-user experience. It's pretty rad.

We're about to drop [some new functionality](https://github.com/smallstep/certificates/issues/300) in the open source CA that will allow you to add the `login@github.com` extension to SSH certificates which should be the last piece you need for your use case. [This blog post](https://smallstep.com/blog/diy-single-sign-on-for-ssh/) is a good place to start if you want to try the SSH CA while you wait for that issue to close (which should happen very soon now). We're also integrating this into our hosted SSO for SSH product if you want the additional features offered there, or if you just don't want to run a CA yourself.

I'll try to remember to swing by with an update once everything is released. In the meantime if you (or anyone else who reads this) is interested I'd love to hear your feedback. I'm mike at smallstep's domain name.

Answer (score 1):

We just launched support for GitHub Certificates in our fully managed [EZSSH product](https://www.keytos.io/ezssh_overview.html) We use your AAD identity to create a short term certificate, you can learn more about it in our [GitHub blog post](https://blog.keytos.io/2021/03/22/Secure-GH.html).

Answer (score -2):

If your organization runs an internal secure web server, if you want to encrypt emails that are exchanged within your organization, or if you use digital certificates to authenticate employees onto the VPN,  then you can setup and act as your own Certificate Authority (CA) and issue your own digital certificates for internal use.

Search the internet for the "Open Source Certificate Authority
 or "Certificate Authority" software to find relevant out of the box solutions.

See also [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) explained in more details.

For GitHub support for SSH certificate authorities it is available with GitHub Enterprise Cloud and GitHub Enterprise Server 2.19+.

More details: https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-ssh-certificate-authorities

https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-your-organizations-ssh-certificate-authorities

Comment: Thanks for the guidance with regards Stack overflow.

Just to clarify, the suggestions you have given all point towards x.509 or SSL certificates. My post was regarding SSH certificates, for which there seems to be very little documentation online.

Comment: @VandanParmar thank you, I now added basic info regarding github ssh CA.